# Limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry for the vagueness of the title, I wasn't sure how else to put it. I've got the question

> Suppose that $h: \mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{ a \right\} \rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}  $ and $h(x) \rightarrow l$ as $x \rightarrow a$. Show that
>   if $l > 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $h(x) > 0$ for all
>   $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Ok, from the definition of limits we have

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{ a \right\}$ such that $0 < |x-a|<\delta$

$|h(x) - l| < \epsilon$

$ - \epsilon < h(x) - l < \epsilon$

$ - \epsilon + l < h(x)  < \epsilon + l$

and I get stuck from here, I know I need to get define $\delta$ such that $ \epsilon + l > 0$ but I'm not seeing where to get this from. I've also thought about it in the different cases, if $l \geq \epsilon$ then the result simply falls out since $l > 0$, however it's when $l < \epsilon$ I'm not seeing the connection with $\delta$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: well why not choose epsilon such that l>epsilon>0 . Such epsilon exists

Comment: Do you mean delta?

Comment: No, epsilon! What we know is that *for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta$ blahblahblah*. In particular, for any $\epsilon\in (0,l)$ there is appropriate $\delta$!

Comment: Yes, what Berci says

Comment: Ah of course yes, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: keep what you have, and let $\epsilon := \frac{l}{2}$ (that's 'ell' in the numerator). Then, in your last line, ...

Comment: Either, you can take $\epsilon:=l$.

Comment: @Berci: correct. I missed your discussions while I was typing. I tend to use 1/2 since ancient times in cases like this, old habit...

Comment: @gnometorule Thanks a lot (and everyone else).

Comment: @Noble: You're very welcome!