# Characterization of continuity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, continuity

So I found that this: $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\|L(x+h)-L(x)\|=0$$ implied continuity. Intuitively, I'd say it means that wherever you approach x from the limit is $L(x)$ but I struggle to see why. How exactly does it relates to the epsilon definition and how do you prove that it does in fact imply the same thing.

Comment: It's a common exercise to show that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity is equivalent to the sequence definition of continuity, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934908/43949).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of limit that your assertion means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\|h\|<\delta\implies\|L(x+h)-L(x)\|<\varepsilon.$$In other words,$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\|y-x\|<\delta\implies\|L(y)-L(x)\|<\varepsilon.$$So, yes, it is equivalent to the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit.

Comment: I see, it is rather clever. Why is that it is not on the Wikipedia page for continuity for example ? It's seem like this definition is really intuitive.

Comment: @Catfoxes It is; see the various equivalent definitions listed under [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition)